# Passing Special Character In Parameter To SQL Server Reporting

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

When i try to pass this string "- !@#$%^&*()_+|}{:"?><<>?/.,';[]`" as a parameter to SQL Server Reporting it crashes.

Here is code sample
ReportParameter[] ReportParams = new ReportParameter[1] { new ReportParameter("Name", HERE-COMES-SPECIALSTRING)

IS there any way to pass special character safely like in SP's we use @ sign for parameter name

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the characters in your string using a backslash?

Best,

Benjamin